# Erro consulta por data

Tags: php, mysql, where

Na minha aplicação tenho uma consulta por data, abaixo está um trecho do script

```
tblacesso.HorarioSaida BETWEEN '2017-06-17 00:00:00' AND '2017-06-17 23:59:59'
```

Mas ele não está selecionando os dados do dia em questão, abaixo está uma imagem no dados no banco.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu alterar para: `tblacesso.HorarioSaida BETWEEN '2017-06-16 00:00:00' AND '2017-06-16 23:59:59'` aparece alguns dados, porém aparece até no dia 17 também.

A query inteira é:

```
$sql = "SELECT tblacesso.Codigo, tblfrota.Codigo AS CodigoFrota, tblpessoa.NomeCompleto, tbldestino.Descricao, tblacesso.KMSaida, tblacesso.KMEntrada, "
        . "DATE_FORMAT(HorarioSaida, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS 'DataSaida', "
        . "DATE_FORMAT(HorarioEntrada, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS 'DataEntrada' "
        . "FROM tblacesso "
        . "INNER JOIN tblfrota ON(tblacesso.FrotaID = tblfrota.Codigo) "
        . "INNER JOIN tblpessoa ON(tblacesso.MotoristaID = tblpessoa.Codigo) "
        . "INNER JOIN tbldestino ON(tblacesso.DestinoID = tbldestino.Codigo)"
        . "WHERE tblacesso.Status = false AND DATE(tblacesso.HorarioSaida) BETWEEN '".$data. " 00:00:00' AND '" .$data." 23:59:59'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tblacesso WHERE HorarioSaida >= '2017-06-16 00:00:00' AND HorarioSaida <= '2017-06-16 23:59:59'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer assim:

```
DATE(tblacesso.HorarioSaida) = '2017-06-17'
```

Comment: Continua não funcionando.

Comment: Qual o tipo do seu campo?

Comment: O campo é Datetime

Comment: Então deveria funcionar, faz assim, posta todo a query para vermos se o problema não é outro.

Comment: tblacesso WHERE HorarioSaida >= '2017-06-16 00:00:00' AND HorarioSaida   <= '2017-06-16 23:59:59'

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
tblacesso.HorarioSaida >= '2017-06-17 00:00:00' AND tblacesso.HorarioSaida <= '2017-06-17 23:59:59'
```